# I get this error when working with jgritman / httpbuilder

Tags: groovy, httpbuilder

I am new to Groovy and following a tutorial.
Any help would be much appreciated.
I also was unsuccessful in using @Grab.

It is a Groovy project without Maven or Gradle.

I have researched and couldn't find a solution, and the tutorial is not updated.

Course: The Complete Apache Groovy Developer Course

```
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

String base = 'http://api.icndb.com'

def chuck = new RESTClient(base)
def params = [firstName: "Dan", lastName: "Vega"]

chuck.contentType = ContentType.JSON
chuck.get( path: '/jokes/random', query: params ) { response, json ->
    println response.status
    println json
}
```

Error

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult
    at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.introspect.MethodInfo.get(MethodInfo.java:70)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.introspect.ClassInfo.getMethods(ClassInfo.java:80)
    at groovyx.net.http.ParserRegistry.<init>(ParserRegistry.java:87)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.<init>(HTTPBuilder.java:194)
    at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.<init>(RESTClient.java:80)
    at com.thesamoanppprogrammer.practicegroovy.restapi.httpbuilder.todos.run(todos.groovy:7)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult
```

Comment: starting from groovy 3.0 `GPathResult` moved to another package: `groovy.xml.slurpersupport.GPathResult`. but according to error `HTTPBuilder` is looking for old package. You have to downgrade groovy version, or upgrade `HTTPBuilder`

Comment: @daggett, I will try your suggestion and let you know; cheers.

Comment: @daggett Fixed error by downgrading groovy to 3.0.9, create answer with your comment and I will accept it and upvote, thanks for your time mate, take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

starting from groovy 3.0 GPathResult moved to another package: `groovy.xml.slurpersupport.GPathResult`.

but according to error `HTTPBuilder`  is looking for old package `groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult`.

You have to downgrade groovy version, or upgrade HTTPBuilder

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Take care.